# Union and Intersection as unary operation on multiple sets in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a recent review of set theory, [here](http://theanalysisofdata.com/probability/A_1.html), I came across a usage of the union and intersection operator as a unary operation on multiple sets for which I am not sure I understand.

Definition A.1.5. For multiple sets $U_α,α∈A$ we define the union and intersection operations as follows:

$\qquad  \underset{\alpha \in A}{\cup}U_\alpha = \{ u:u \in U_\alpha \text{ for one or more } \alpha \in A \}$ 
$\qquad \underset{\alpha \in A}{\cap}U_\alpha = \{ u:u \in U_\alpha \text{ for all of } \alpha \in A \}$

It seems to me that the union statement is saying if $\alpha$ is an element in any of the sets in the multiple sets then it is included in the union set. Conversely, it would need to be in all the sets within the multiple sets to be included in the intersection.

Example: 
$A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ 
$U_\alpha = \{\{1,2\}, \{2, 3\}, \{2, 4, 5\}\}$ 
$\underset{\alpha \in A}{\cup}U_\alpha = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} $
$\underset{\alpha \in A}{\cap}U_\alpha = \{2\} $

Is this correct or am I misunderstanding the notation?

Note: In the original question I sometimes said multiple sets and other times multiset.  Thank you drhab for catching my error.

Comment: Yes.  I just noticed the error in the title.  That was probably part of my initial confusion.  Thank you!

Comment: I discovered another mistake give me some time . We do not have $U_{\alpha}=\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{2,4,5\}\}$ but e.g. $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $U_1=\{1,2\}$, $U_2=\{2,3\}$ and $U_3=\{2,4,5\}$. In that case $\bigcup_{a\in A}U_{\alpha}=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $\bigcap_{a\in A}U_{\alpha}=\{2\}$.

Comment: In that case $A$ functions as index set.

Comment: Thank you drhab.  It makes much more sense now as completely separate entities.